# Model and ViewModel Relation in Swift (MVVM)

Tags: swift, mvvm

I'm trying to learn MVVM pattern for almost a month and got a little bit struggling with a certain scenario :

There is an array of boolean = `arrayOfItems`
There are 3 `TableViewController` inside a `PageViewController` = table A B C

- ABC will show data from an arrayOfItems, so all of them will show the same data
- A has `removeData` function, if it is triggered then BC should be updated
- ABC have `selectItem` function (cell being selected), let says that ABC got its own array to control isSelectedItem, so when it is triggered it only impact the current tableVC
- arrayOfItems is being updated every 10 seconds, if it is updated ABC should `refreshAllData` without changing `isSelectedItem` array

So far what I have done are :

- Create a model called Item which has: `var dataList: [Bool] = [] and a removeItemAtIndex func`
- Create ItemProtocol which has: `var isSelectedItems: [Bool] { get }`
- Create ItemViewModel conform ItemProtocol:
- ```
   class ItemViewModel: NSObject, ItemProtocol {
   var item: Item

   // MARK: ItemProtocol
   var isSelected: [Bool] = []

   // MARK: Init
   init(withItem item: Item) {
       self.item = item
       for _ in self.item.dataList {
           self.isSelected.append(true)
       }
   }

   func updateIsSelected(isSelected: Bool, index: Int) {
       self.isSelected[index] = isSelected
   }
   }
  ```
- and then inside my pageVC i will assign :

```
A.viewModel = ItemViewModel(withItem: self.item)
B.viewModel = ItemViewModel(withItem: self.item) 
C.viewModel = ItemViewModel(withItem: self.item)
```

- the item is coming from previous page, but in pageVC we need to monitor its status so item will updated every 10s
- The problem when I use my approach is when I remove the an item on A, BC will not updated.
- the question is what is the best approach to control arrayOfItem without disrupting the isSelectedItems using MVVM pattern, and where should I call updateItem? in model Item or in the ItemViewModel?

Comment: Please go through the question and check the code and the naming, what is the model and what is the view model. For instance `A.viewModel = Item(withItem: self.item)` here it looks like you assign a model object as view model to your controller???

Comment: Updated the question, i am writting on my phone On my way home lol..

Comment: Why you do not create a single View Model which contains the array of data then inject this view model in the three controllers and any controller wants to update the data in the view model, will call the view model and so every controller listen to this view model will be updated?

Comment: @EssamMohamedFahmi I will try. thanks